# View a dendrogram with perfectly synced heatmap

Tags: javascript, visualization, heatmap, dendrogram

For the given link
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cpj95/pen/djOwYG?editors=0010)

```
var layout2 = {

yaxis: {
domain: [0, 0.7],
mirror: false,
showgrid: false,
showline: false,
zeroline: false,
showticklabels: true,
ticks: "",
ticktext: ["n", "o", "p", "j", "q", "l", "k", "m", "r"],
tickvals: [-5.0, -15.0, -25.0, -35.0, -45.0, -55.0, -65.0,-75.0,-85.0]},

xaxis: {
domain: [0, 0.7],
mirror: false,
showgrid: false,
showline: false,
zeroline: false,
showticklabels: true,
ticks: "",
ticktext: ["n", "o", "p", "j", "q", "l", "k", "m", "r"],
tickvals: [5.0, 15.0, 25.0, 35.0, 45.0, 55.0, 65.0, 75.0, 85.0]
},

xaxis2: {
domain: [0.75, 1],
mirror: false,
showgrid: false,
showline: false,
zeroline: false,
showticklabels: false,
ticks: "",
ticktext: ["n", "o", "p", "j", "q", "l", "k", "m", "r"]
},

yaxis2: {
domain: [0.75, 1],
mirror: false,
showgrid: false,
showline: false,
zeroline: false,
showticklabels: false,
ticks: "",
ticktext: ["n", "o", "p", "j", "q", "l", "k", "m", "r"]
},
showlegend: false,
margin: { l: 30, r: 30, b: 30, t: 30 }};

data = dendrogramUP["data"];
data = data.concat(dendrogramRIGHT["data"]);

trace4["x"] = dendrogramUP["layout"]["xaxis"]["tickvals"];
trace4["y"] = dendrogramRIGHT["layout"]["yaxis"]["tickvals"];
data = data.concat(trace4);

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout2);
```

I am trying to get a heatmap and a dendrogram on the top(top down) . Ignore the right side dendrogram.
Y axis for heatmap should have 9 items  whereas X axis should have 5 items and accordingly the heatmap plot.

The problem is that the dendrogramUp is not aligning with the heat map properly as you can see and I'm not sure if the dendrogramUp data is correct or not.Please tell how to procedd in debugging the issue or just please solve it. I believe some tinkering is needed in the variable layout 2 .